# SQL Query - Count Group By Very Slow - Help Optimise

Tags: mysql

Please see my mysql query below that I want to optimize. I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this but I just cant for the life of me work it out. Could someone please help? I think there must be a way of preventing the multiple inner joins per group by.

```
SELECT network_name, count(*) as phone_count from 
deals_temp d 
         INNER JOIN phones p ON d.model_id = p.model_id
         INNER JOIN tariffs t ON d.tariff_id = t.tariff_id
         INNER JOIN networks n ON d.network_id = n.network_id
         INNER JOIN free_gift fg ON d.freegift_id = fg.freegift_id 
         INNER JOIN merchants m ON d.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
         INNER JOIN type ty ON ty.type_id = d.type_id 
WHERE network_name != ''  GROUP BY network_name UNION ALL 

SELECT tariff_contractlength, count(*) as phone_count from 
deals_temp d 
         INNER JOIN phones p ON d.model_id = p.model_id
         INNER JOIN tariffs t ON d.tariff_id = t.tariff_id
         INNER JOIN networks n ON d.network_id = n.network_id
         INNER JOIN free_gift fg ON d.freegift_id = fg.freegift_id 
         INNER JOIN merchants m ON d.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
         INNER JOIN type ty ON ty.type_id = d.type_id 
WHERE tariff_contractlength != 1  GROUP BY tariff_contractlength UNION ALL 

SELECT offer_freegift, count(*) as phone_count from deals_temp d 
         INNER JOIN phones p ON d.model_id = p.model_id
         INNER JOIN tariffs t ON d.tariff_id = t.tariff_id
         INNER JOIN networks n ON d.network_id = n.network_id
         INNER JOIN free_gift fg ON d.freegift_id = fg.freegift_id 
         INNER JOIN merchants m ON d.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
         INNER JOIN type ty ON ty.type_id = d.type_id  
WHERE offer_freegift != ''  GROUP BY offer_freegift
```

Ok I will explain some more and simply it. I thought it may be pretty quick.

So I have the following tables

**deals_temp**

model_id    | tariff_id |

123         | 1234

123         | 1235

123         | 1236

124         | 1237

**phones**

model_id    | model_make            | model_basename

123     | Apple         | iPhone

124     | Apple         | iPad

**tariff**

tariff_id   | tariff_name

1234        | Unlimited 30

I need to count the number of deals(rows) in deals_temp based on the distinct values in the other tables e.g. phones (model_make) and tariff (tariff_name)

The output should be:

element     | count

iPhone      | 123

iPad        | 543

Apple       | 453

Unlimted 30 | 564

Comment: Why are you doing count(*)? Can you not just count the unique IDs of each row?

Comment: Like we have any idea what data you have, what table structure and expected output. How do you think we should be able to help you with the info you provide?

Comment: Very well said by @juergend +1.

Comment: You basically have three different queries here concatenated by `UNION ALL`, and you're asking for optimization advice for all three. Attempt to optimize them one by one: look at EXPLAIN, look at the indexes you're providing, etc. It's hard for anyone who doesn't understand your tables to understand what you're trying to count.

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to make sure you have indexes on all your id fields that you are inner joining to.

Second step would be to make sure you have indexes on variables you are referencing in your where clauses.  (network_name, tariff_contractlength, offer_freegift)

Beyond that when you take away the unions you have some very straight forward queries meaning they don't look very complex.

Not sure if mySQL has a query optimizer you can review but that would be a place to start.  My guess from looking at your query is that the majority of its time is being spent joining your data, which means either you need to not join so much data, or beef up your server stats, or start building cubes.....(i would not recommend the last two)

Comment: Thanks for th reply. All of the join fields are set as a primary key so I think naturally they are indexed anyway? That's the reason for the post, I want to know if there is a way to stop all the multiple joins and just have one join once, and then the counting is done from that table. The only thing that comes to mind is what you said about creating a cube / new table so I can refer to it in every query. Any more thoughts anyone? Is there an easier way to do this in one query?